# Dynamically create new files within a Linux filesystem driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm working on a Linux filesystem driver and I've got the hang of generating a superblock, creating inodes and dentry's, and making them handle reads and writes.

Now, though, I want the driver to be able to present new files to the user dynamically. **Basically, my question is: how can I do this?**

Let's say, for a silly example, every time the user reads from a file, we create a new file. Intuitively, I would want to just create a new inode and dentry, and link them together. The problem here is that in my file reading callback function I have no access to the superblock (I think), which means I can't make a new inode.

I won't post the code for my driver since it's too long, even to create a minimal example, but for a general overview: the `file_system_type` struct's mount function calls `mount_nodev`, and then in my function to fill the superblock I setup the root directory and create a file named "file1".

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So, you are creating a new filesystem, right?

Comment: "The problem here is that in my file reading callback function I have no access to the superblock" - File object has `f_inode` field which points to inode. inode object has `i_sb` field which points to the super block. Also, a filesystem normally embed base `inode` object into its own object type, so using by `file->f_inode` you could obtain reference to the object with the type created by you, and this type could contain all needed fields.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yep, that's right

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, this is a good starting point, I'll try and get something working

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've worked out a solution from your comment and submitted it as an answer, but if you'd like to write up an answer yourself based on what you already wrote I'd be happy to mark yours as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on information from a comment by @Tsyvarev, I can indeed create a file dynamically in the same exact fashion as when I first set up the filesystem, taking the superblock from the `struct file*`'s linked inode!